# Automating creating streams in Graylog

Tags: graylog

I need to automate the stream creation in Graylog. Currently, we are login into the Graylog portal and creating streams manually for errors and information. Is there a way that we can automate or create custom templates so that we can remove the manual effort of creating streams for different env( QA, UAT, PROD etc)

Answer (score 1):

There is a rest [API](https://www.graylog.org/features/api) to automate Graylog.

There is also Hundreds of Add-ons for Graylog on the [Graylog market place](https://marketplace.graylog.org/) including software libraries for various programming languages.

Comment: Hey @Gerhard do you have any example to share for the same so that I can look into it